# How to see a list of all my SourceSafe check-in comments in a certain time range?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

A co-worker of mine wants me to describe to her all the changes that I made to a project during the month of January this year.

I would like to know how I can make SourceSafe enumerate a list of all files that have been modified during January, when they were modified, and the check-in comments.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try History, select all items and then Report?

Comment: I tried that option, but the problem is that it doesn't display the comments unless I click "details", in which case they are displayed *one at a time*, which is unacceptable to me because there are so many files.  I finally discovered that by clicking on "Report", I can export all the comments into a text-file, but this is still not that convenient.

Answer (score 0):

We use [VSSReporter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4709/VssReporter-2-1-A-Visual-SourceSafe-reporting-tool). You can search for files, versions, labels and comments, based on user and/or check-in date. You can then export the report as tab-delimited, formatted or XML, or you can export the files themselves. And it's open source, so if there's some feature missing, you can add it yourself.